# Maven plugins can not be found in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After updating IntelliJ from version 12 to 13, the following Maven-related plugins cannot be resolved:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin
```

When using IntelliJ 12, these were not in the plugins list. Somehow they've been added after the update and now IntelliJ complains they cannot be found. Where can I remove these plugins from the list OR resolve the problem by installing them?

I can run maven goals `clean` and `compile` without problem, but the profile/plugins appear red with warnings in the IDE.

**EDIT after 8 years:** *Please also have a look at all other good answers here. The accepted answer is a common solution but might not work for you or for your IDE version*

Comment: Press Ctrl + Alt + S.Go to plugins. Is "Maven integration" checked?

Comment: @memainjm yes it is checked

Comment: Uncheck the "Work offline" checkbox in Maven settings.

Comment: why not accept the first answer? IT seems to work

Comment: I have found that during Idea updated, the idea Program-Files folder has changed. Idea in settings has the location of maven plugin, which was incorrect (pointing to the old folder). - File->Settings->Build,Exec...->Build Tools->Maven

Answer (score 497, accepted):

For newer versions of IntelliJ, enable the use plugin registry option within the Maven settings as follows:

1. Click **File  Settings**.
2. Expand **Build, Execution, Deployment  Build Tools  Maven**.
3. Check **Use plugin registry**.
4. Click **OK** or **Apply**.

For IntelliJ 14.0.1, open the preferences---not settings---to find the plugin registry option:

1. Click **File  Preferences**.

Regardless of version, also invalidate the caches:

1. Click **File  Invalidate Caches / Restart**.
2. Click **Invalidate and Restart**.

When IntelliJ starts again the problem should be vanquished.

Comment: For Mac users, you can find it under Preferences.
(Click on IntelliJ IDEA on the menu bar-> Preferences) or (Command⌘+,) ->(Same as above)Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven.

Comment: I'm using version 20.x.x. This didn't work for me. Could it be another problem?

Comment: @manikanta nvsr:Could you check that 1) that 'Use plugin registry' is activated? 2) Within your Maven local repo that the dep is there but not really downloaded? In this case remove the directory and synch again (button on the right). It solved the problem for me.

Comment: using Invalidate and Restart, works for me. Am using IntellIj 2020.03.

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't a default in Intellij? This should be enabled by default.

Comment: I was also wondering why they haven't enabled it by default.

Comment: Not solving the issue

Comment: did not solve the issue for me in 2022.1

Comment: 2 years later, and your answer still useful, Thank you so much, I have been looking for a solution for the last 2 days.

Comment: This is how it can be solved in 2022.1 IntelliJ version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639836/plugin-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin-not-found

Comment: not solving the issue for IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks:
`IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Community Edition)`
`Build #IC-221.5787.30, built on May 31, 2022`

Comment: I also needed to do `mvn dependency:resolve`

Comment: **Use plugin registry** seems to be gone from IntelliJ 2023.3.2. Why? An archived [copy of the plugin registry](http://web.archive.org/web/20141224212337/https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-registry.html), via a [2008 IntelliJ post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206190609-Maven-Use-Plugin-Registry-what-does-it-do), led me to it being [deleted from maven-site in 2015](https://github.com/apache/maven-site/commit/71bd13cb47140eaa5e13b2b4e242387f6847348b#diff-0956106786f217d31b8eef41fdf9c8a716d53a3e6a66129e86f94607fce010f0).

Comment: FWIW I needed the *combination* of the next three top answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44883900/1101109) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499557/1101109) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40308560/1101109) , doing [2] last, to make all my project warnings go away.

Answer (score 99):

I had this problem for years with the maven-deploy plugin, and the error showed up even though I was not directly including the plugin in my POM. As a work-around I had to force include the plugin with a version into my POMs plugin section just to remove the red-squiggly.

After trying every solution on Stack Overflow, I found the problem: Looking into my `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin` directory there was a version 'X.Y' along with '2.8.2' et al. So I deleted the entire maven-deploy-plugin directory, and then re-imported my Maven project.

So it seems the issue is an IntelliJ bug in parsing the repository.  I would not not remove the entire repository though, just the plugins that report an error.

Comment: Nice. I had a few of these due to IntelliJ battling my company's proxy server. Finally blew them out. Thanks!

Comment: "update maven indices" (under ctrl + enter) after that

Comment: I didn't have the issue of the local repository being corrupted. But adding the version did it.

Comment: Where is that directory?

Comment: Found it (Windows 10):
"C:\Users\your_user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin\". 
I had only 1 file inside another directory there. I removed folder, IntelliJ redownloaded it, but then there were couple files, including .jar. Before that I had 2 to 5 errors in IntelliJ, after that I have only 1. The same as before with that folder.

Comment: Replying to @fan: "I didn't have the issue of the local repository being corrupted" - it doesn't need to be corrupted, just if there is a newer version, the old one can't be override and that's the reason it's not updated.

Comment: This also worked for me, thanks.

Comment: This issues fixed it for me. For me it was org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin

Comment: This worked for me as well :+1

Comment: This gave me an insight. I just completely deleted everything under `/repository` and made IntelliJ do its thing again. No error so far

Comment: It works nice a charm

Answer (score 80):

Run a Force re-import from the maven tool window. If that does not work, Invalidate your caches (*File > Invalidate caches*) and restart. Wait for IDEA to re-index the project.

Comment: For my colleague, force re-import worked when plugins had not been shown in the right maven panel.

Comment: it worked for me. It seems it was using an outdated settings.xml

Comment: How do you do a force reimport in IntelliJ?

Comment: @a-p From the Maven tool window, click the "Reload all Maven Projects" button (it's the left most button and looks like two arrows in a circle, much like most refresh icons.) It use to be labeled "Re-import..." rather than "Reload...", hence why in my above answer I said "re-import". They changed the nomenclature used a few years ago.

Answer (score 70):

None of the other answers worked for me. The solution that worked for me was to download the missing artifact manually via cmd:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ -Dartifact=ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.8.0
```

After this change need to let know the Idea about new available artifacts. This can be done in "Settings > Maven > Repositories", select there your "Local" and simply click "Update".

**Edit**: the -DrepoUrl seems to be deprecated. -DremoteRepositories should be used instead. Source: [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin – dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html).

Comment: So even after I deleted \.m2\repository\, I was finding that my \.m2\repository\com\whatever\thing\my-plugin\1.2.3  was only "partially' being populated.  I deleted the 1.2.3 directory and did what you say here, and then it looked correct populated.  I think this is the "nail" solution vs the hammer solution of deleting \.m2\repository    thanks.

Comment: I tried everything else in this thread, only this one resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: I think that this should be the right answer, probably it's the main cause when plugins are not found. Apparently plugin dependencies are not downloaded until the associated profile is enabled (I looked into the maven repository and plugins marked in red where missing). I would try this before to delete the whole m2 repository (it can take some time to re-download).

Comment: I tried many solutions and this was the only one that worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: This one worked for me loading a project that was built using an older version of IntelliJ. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you. I had (and hated) that problem for months..

Comment: still accurate with IntelliJ CE 2022.1. I already had the jar in my local repo so updating the local repo fixed it. Thx

Answer (score 46):

The red with warnings **maven-site-plugin** resolved after the build **site** Lifecycle:

[image]

My IntelliJ version is Community 2017.2.4

Comment: This downloaded all my missing maven plugins.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Same for the clean, compile, install, but NOT deploy lifecycles, for which I get the following error `Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter`

Comment: Thank you! It worked for Community 2021.3.2

Answer (score 41):

**SOLVED !!!**

This is how I fixed the issue...

1. Tried one of the answers which include 'could solve it by enabling "use plugin registry" '. Did enable that but no luck.
2. Tried again one of the answers in the thread which says 'If that does not work, Invalidate your caches (File > Invalidate caches) and restart.' Did that but again no luck.
3. Tried These options ..
   Go to Settings --> Maven --> Importing and made sure the following was selected

   Import Maven projects automatically

   Create IDEA modules for aggregator projects Keep source...

   Exclude build dir...

   Use Maven output...

   Generated souces folders: "detect automatically"

   Phase to be...: "process-resources"

   Automatically download: "sources" & "documentation"

   Use Maven3 to import

   project VM options for importer: -Xmx512m

   But again no success.

   4. Now lets say I had 10 such plugins which didn't get resolve and among them the 
      first was **'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin'**
      I went to **'.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/'** and deleted the directory 
      'maven-site-plugin' and did a maven reimport again. Guess what, particular 
      missing plugin got dowloaded. And I just followed similar steps for other 
      missing plugins and all got resolved.

Comment: And on Windows 10 that directory is here: "C:\Users\your_user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin\". I had only 1 file inside another directory there. I removed folder, IntelliJ redownloaded it, but then there were couple files, including .jar. Before that I had 2 to 5 errors in IntelliJ, after that I have only 1. The same as before with that folder.

Comment: 4th one is an effective solution.. I think deleting repo finally works in any maven conflict case :)

Comment: In short, delete the folder for the offending dependency from inside repository (.m2/repository/path/to/offending/dependency)

Comment: Deleting folders of missing plugins is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: This is the only really working solution

Comment: no idea how this works, but it does. I tried deleting the whole .m2 and reimporting everything but even that doesnt work, but deleting the plugin part works?

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue. I added the plugins into my pom.xml dependencies and it works for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I tried all the 'above' answers before finally caving and adding the declaration directly in my projects pom.xml
This is a less-than-optimal solution because we have to add the maven plugins to each new project.

Edit: I took this one step further and now REMOVED the declaration. Now the inspection error is gone...

Comment: Helped me. I added the repository once, removed it and then it works well.

Answer (score 22):

I tried the other answers, but none of them solved this problem for me.

The problem disappeared when I explicitly added the `groupId` like this:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Once the color of the version number changed from red to black and the problem disappeared from the `Problems` tab the `groupId` can be removed again from the problematic plugin, the error does not show up again and the version number even shows up as suggestion for `version`.

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. What remains unexplained, however, is what is the cause of this bizarre behaviour, especially considering that `org.apache.maven.plugins` is the [default value](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin) of `groupId`?

Comment: @Marchyello the most likely reason is the bug in IntelliJ maven plugin. It just expects that each plugin has a groupId, when it is completly fine to omit one for maven own plugins.

Answer (score 13):

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.6 and found out, that the feature **Reimport All Maven Project** does not use the JDK, which is set in the Settings: *Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner*. 
Instead it uses it's own JRE in `IntelliJ_HOME/jre64/` by default. You can configure the JDK for the *Importer* in *Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing*.

In my specific problem, an SSL certificate was missing in the JREs keystore. Unfortunately IDEA only logs this issue in it's own logfile. A little red box to inform about the RuntimeException had been *really* nice...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Did the above, then deleted the problematic plugin directories, then Reimport and voila!

Comment: This worked for me. I also did the comment given by @Vlad. Upvoted both answer and comment. Intellij Version 2019.2 installed after formatting the machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me after struggling for 1 day.

Comment: To update the cacerts file did it for me (using an own nexus with own SSL certificate). The cacerts file has a default password of "changeit". https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206153629-How-to-add-a-SSL-root-certificate-to-IDEA-on-OS-X-.

You import the own crt file with: 

keytool.exe -import -alias mynexus -keystore <path to file>\cacerts -file <path to file>\dataic.crt

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error and was able to get rid of it by deleting my old Maven settings file. Then I updated the Maven plugins manually using the mvn command:

```
mv ~/.m2/settings.xml ~/.m2/settings.xml.old
mvn -up
```

Finally I ran the "Reimport All Maven Projects" button in the Maven Project tab in IntelliJ. The errors vanished in my case.

Answer (score 11):

None of the other solutions worked for me.

My solution:

Maven Settings -> Repositories -> select Local Repository in the list, Update

Worked like a charm!

Comment: In my case, I had to update the cloud maven repository index as well in the same page.

On my mac the navigation was:
Preferences > Maven > Repositories > select required Repository > click on Update > Apply.

Answer (score 8):

This did the trick for me...delete all folders and files under 'C:\Users[Windows User Account].m2\repository'.

Finally ran 'Reimport All Maven Projects' in the Maven Project tab in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 7):

Remove your local Maven unknown plugin and reimport all maven projects. This will fix this issue.

You can find it under `View > Tool Windows > Maven` :

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For me it was as simple as giving the plugin a version:

```
<version>3.3.0</version>
```

The full plugin code sample is given below:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Before the version you must force to download the correct version. Then it perfectly run.

Answer (score 5):

I was recently faced with the same issue. None of the other solutions resolved the red error lines.

What I did was run the actual targets in question (deploy, site). I could see those dependencies then being fetched.

After that, a reimport did the trick.

Comment: Seems like intellij didnt auto download these plugins without actually runing the maven goal. Kind of makes sense:-) Worked for me even if the actual site and deploy goals did fail :-)

Answer (score 5):

If an artifact is not resolvable.
Go in the directory of your .m2/repository
and check that you DON'T have that kind of file :

build-helper-maven-plugin-1.10.pom.lastUpdated

If you don't have any artefact in the folder, just delete it, and try again to re-import in IntelliJ.

the content of those files is like :

```
#NOTE: This is an Another internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Fri Mar 10 10:36:12 CET 2017
@default-central-https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1489138572430
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo\:build-helper-maven-plugin\:pom\:1.10 from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: connect timed out
```

Without the *.lastUpdated file, IntelliJ (or Eclipse by the way) is enabled to reload what is missing.

Comment: Thx! this finally did the trick for me so you guys could try to
cd ~/.m2/repository && find . -type f -name '*lastUpdated' | xargs rm

Comment: Only this one helped me. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

For me which worked is putting the repository which contained the plugin under pluginRepository tags. Example,

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>pcentral</id>
        <name>pcentral</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

1. Go to Settings --> Maven --> Importing --> JDK for importer -->
   use "Use Project JDK" option instead of a custom JDK set previously.
2. Re-build/re-import all the dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I could solve this problem by changing "Maven home directory" from "Bundled (Maven 3) to "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5/libexec" in the maven settings of IntelliJ (14.1.2).

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck the "Work offline" checkbox in Maven settings.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I tried to fix the issue and it worked:

1. Manually deleted the existing plugin from the .m2 repo
2. Enabled "use plugin registry" in IntelliJ
3. Invalidated the cache and restarted IntelliJ
4. Reimported the maven project in IntelliJ

After following above steps, the issue was fixed. Hopefully this helps you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Enabling "use plugin registry" and Restart project after invalidate cash solved my problem

to  Enabling "use plugin registry" >>> (intelij) File > Setting > Maven > enable the option from the option list of maven

To invalidate cash >>> file > invalidate cash

That's it...

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. Could you please explain what it actually does?

Comment: @NIKHILCHAURASIA The Maven Clean Plugin, attempts to clean the files and directories generated by Maven during its build. While there are plugins that generate additional files, the Clean Plugin assumes that these files are generated inside the target directory.
When considering about maven-deploy-plugin
deploying means not only copying the artifacts but making sure all this information is correctly updated. But if these files override with cashed files, it may course errors

Comment: @NIKHILCHAURASIA When executing Maven, it'll first look in this local cache for artifacts. If the artifact cannot be found here, Maven will access the remote repositories to find the artifact. Once found it will be stored into the local repository, so it's available for current and future usage.

Answer (score 4):

Deleted all folders from below and did the "Reload All Maven Projects" refresh button and it worked for me.

```
C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- Close IDEA
- Delete "***.iml**" and "**.idea**" -directories(present in the root folder of project)
- Run "**mvn clean install**" from the command-line
- Re-import your project into IDEA

After re-importing the entire project, installation of dependencies will start which will take some minutes to complete depending upon your internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

My case:

- `maven-javadoc-plugin` with version `3.2.0` is displayed red in IntelliJ.
- Plugin is present in my local maven repo.
- Re-imported maven million times.
- Ran `mvn clean install` from the command line N times.
- All my maven settings in IntelliJ are correct.
- Tried to switch between Bundled and non-bundled Maven.
- Tried do delete the whole maven repo and to delete only the plugin from it.
- Nothing of the above worked.
- **The only thing that almost always helps with modern IntelliJ IDEA versions is "Invalidate caches / Restart".** It helped this time as well. `maven-javadoc-plugin` is not red anymore, and I can click on it and to to the source `pom` file of the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I faced the same issue.
All tips doesn't work in my cause.

But I fix it.

Go to Intellij idea setting, find Maven, and in it you need to open Repository tab and update maven and local repos. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

June/2021:

No Delete, No Reimport.

What I did is,  I was going to :

```
C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins
```

Then double Click on every Plugin Folders, And see what version it is downloaded.

Then I came back to pom file, and according to downloaded version, I carefully changes those versions in `<version>....</version>` Tags. Then refresh.

And That way, All red marks are gone, Even gone those Yellow Marks.

All Clean.

Here is my full pom file for further notice. The Project is JavaFx+Maven with Shade :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>main.java.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThreeColumnTable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/generated-groovy-stubs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: But why does it happen? What's the reason, shouldn't the plugins only be downloaded in the respected versions?

Comment: Generally people don't provide version and may be defaulted version is not the one that is existing. Another reason is wrong plugin version mentioned in the pom so that will not be found either. The key @Noor Hossain has mentioned is provide the right version and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have red squiggles underneath the project in the Maven plugin, try clicking the "Reimport All Maven Projects" button (looks like a refresh symbol).

[image: Reimport all Maven Projects]

Answer (score 2):

You can add them as dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Intellij will resolve them. After successfull import dependencies, you can clean them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the plugins which cannot be found (maven-site-plugin,maven-resources-plugin)
2. go to '.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/'
3. delete the directory rm -rf plugin-directory-name (eg: rm -rf maven-site-plugin)
4. exit project from intellij
5. import project again
6. Do a Maven reimport

Explanation: when you do a maven reimport, it will download all the missing plugins again.

*Happy Coding*

Answer (score 2):

I use the community edition packaged as snap on Ubuntu 18.04.

I experience that issue each time there a IntelliJ release.

In that scenario, my working solution is to invoke the invalidate cache and restart from the file menù flagging the indexes removal too.

Answer (score 1):

Goto IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Plugin

Search for maven, you will see
1. Maven Integration
2. Maven Integration Extension.

Select the Maven Integration option and restart your Intellij

Answer (score 1):

For me, I download them manually and put theme in my .m2 folder then i did invalidate cache and restart (I m using Intellij IDEA).
The steps are for example:

> ```
> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>               <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>2.0</version>
> ```

1. I go to https://mvnrepository.com/ then serch for 
   jdepend-maven-plugin choose the version 2.0
2. In Files go and click on View All
3. Download this files jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.jar
                      jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.jar.sh1
                      jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.pom
                      jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.pom.sh1
4. go to .m2 folder then  org/codehaus/mojo Create folder with name  jdepend-maven-plugin inside with name
    2.0 inside put the 4 files downloaded befor.
5. create file with name _remote.repositories open it with text editor and write inside

> jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.jar>central=
>   jdepend-maven-plugin-2.0.pom>central=

6. go to intellij IDEA invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, After checking the pom.xml file, found out that I have duplicated plugins for the surefire. After deleting and leaving only 1 inside the pom.xml - issue resolved.

Also maven-surefire-report-plugin == LATEST
and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the Plugins were related to a Profile.
I have to enable the relevant profile via Maven (right sidebar menu), Profiles and let the dependencies download.

Answer (score 1):

Tried invalidating cache, reimporting the project, removing .m2 folder partially and as a whole, and switching to the Idea bundled Maven.
Nothing worked, and I've finally broken Maven completely: when it would build the project in the console, now it stopped.
Had to reinstall Maven, and it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the following code in your pom.xml. If this does not work, try to change the `<version>2.8.2</version>` (diferent versions can be found in the maven repo.)

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Needed to specify the groupId and the version.

Answer (score 1):

I just delete all my maven plugins stored in `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins`, and IntelliJ downloaded  all the plugins again a it solve my problem and it worked fine for me!!!

Comment: I've been trying several options but this is the one that worked for me. But maybe it's because another steps I made that affected too.

Answer (score 1):

If you already tried to clear your `.m2` folder, used "*Invalidate Caches*" and "*Restart*, double-checked the plugin declarations in your POM file, then:

**1. Check the IntelliJ Maven configuration**

- Ctrl+Shift+A
- Type "*Maven Settings*"
- Tick "*Use plugin registry*"
- Double-check your "*Maven home path*" and "*User settings file*"
- Try to get additional logs: set "*Output level*" to "*Debug*" and click "*Apply*"

**2. Check the IntelliJ Java configuration**

- Ctrl+Shift+A
- Type "*Importing*"
- Double-check the JDK used in "*JDK for importer*"

**3. Update your `cacerts` keystore file**

Make sure you trust the TLS server certificate of the remote Maven repository. For that, add the public certificate(s) to the `cacerts` keystore under `/path/to/jdk/jre/lib/security/` (for instance by using https://keystore-explorer.org/) - default password is "changeit"

If you can't edit the file:

- Ctrl+Shift+A
- Type "*Importing*"
- Update "*VM options for importer*" with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit` and click "*Apply*"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were two slightly different dependences (version 2.1 vs 2.0) in two maven sub-modules. After I switched to a single version the error has gone in IDEA 14. (Refresh and .m2 swipe didn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

I have change the Maven home directory from Bundled(Maven 3) to Bundled(Maven 2) in the maven setting. And this works for me. Have a try!

Answer (score 0):

["IntelliJ IDEA and Maven - "Unresolved Plugin" Solutions"](https://gist.github.com/kdevo/05542ea81905d12199019699962171de) - in particular, deleting the plugin-folder - then reimporting all maven plugins after ide restart - worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this might help someone down the line

i faced similar issues, my system was not able to resolve the proxy server
so connected to the local wifi hotpsot.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a mistake in the settings.xml. I was using http:// in the url due to which it wasn't working. Once i removed it the plugins were downloaded successfully.

```
<proxy>
   <id>optional</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <host>www-proxy.xxxx.com</host>
   <port>80</port>
  <!-- <nonProxyHosts>local.net</nonProxyHosts>-->
  </proxy>

  <!-- Proxy for HTTPS -->
  <proxy>
   <id>optional1</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <host>www-proxy.xxxx.com</host>
   <port>80</port>
   <!--<nonProxyHosts>local.net</nonProxyHosts>-->
  </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

If problem persist, you can add manually the missing plugins files.

For example if maven-site-plugins is missing, go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-site-plugin

Choice your version, and download files associated directly into your `.m2` folder, in this example : `C:\Users\ {USERNAME} \.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin\ {VERSION}`

In IntelliJ IDEA, open Maven sidebar, and reload (tooltip : Reimport All Maven projects)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried most of the answers above. I solve this problem by:

- Cleaning all items in the `.m2/repository` folder
- Uninstall Intellij Ultimate Version
- Install Community Version

It so amazingly worked!

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. After a painful few hours, it turned out that the issue was caused by the way I imported the project.

**Context:** importing freshly generated Spring Initializr project with Web & Kafka dependencies.

**Issue:** plugin dependency was "Not found" and IntelliJ couldn't compile the app, even though `mvn clean compile` ran fine on the console.

**The bad way:** Importing it using the "New > Project from Existing Sources..." option.

**The good way:** Importing it using the "Open..." option.

**Solution to go from the bad to the good:** remove the project, delete and re-clone the repo from version control to make sure all gitignored IntelliJ files are removed, and import it into IntelliJ with the "Open..." option.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the dependency

This question is old, but I hope my answer will help those who find it

Reference
[link]
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.1.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the dependency in dependencies, and solved my problem:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I neglected the <*pluginManagement*>, it's as <*dependencyManagement*> which is different from <*dependencies*>:

**dependencyManagement only declares dependencies, it does not introduce them.**

So whether I clean all items in my repository folder or type *mvn clean install -e -U*, both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error for a long time until this solution solved my problem:

Try deleting the maven-site-plugin directory from your local repository (located at `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin`) and running `mvn clean install` again.

Comment: does it add anything to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65332786/7769052?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete the following build plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and I added the following taken from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010178219-Cannot-resolve-plugin-org-apache-maven-plugins-

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (which worked for me): as only IDEA fails, but Maven CLI works, the issue must be completely on the IDE side. To have an homogeneous behavior, go to

**Build, Execution, Deployment → Built Tools → Maven**

and set the *Maven home path* to the system installation (so to not use the bundled version).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for intelliJ 2023 for Mac, I had to add the dependency of each plugin that showed an error, for example for the plugin with artifactId: maven-compiler-plugin I had to add the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.11.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

After that the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Using the plugin registry, reloading all maven projects, or invalidating the caches and restarting did not resolve my issue. The IDE complained that the plugin could not be resolved. The important thing is to ensure that it is being executed in the correct order.

This is the steps to debug the issue:

1. go to ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins and rm -rf all plugins that were not resolvable.
2. Click on reload all maven projects. (now instead of saying the plugin is unresolvable, it will show an error log of some sort, in my case the proxy I was using could not be connected as it was an old proxy setting in settings.xml)
3. I went to ~/.m2/settings.xml and changed the proxy to the correct one.
4. invalidate caches and restart
5. rm -rf all unresolvable plugins
6. reload all maven projects

Comment: Duplicated comment with others

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution

Remove the plugins from your local repository under .m2 folder which displays the error like:

- maven-install-plugin, and
- maven-deploy-plugin

i.e.

```
rm -rf .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin
rm -rf .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin
```

And then add the plug-in in the pom.xml as given here:

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Then rebuild your project. BOOM!
it should work.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I removed the dependencies for Postgress data base in Spring boot:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

what I did was click on **file > invalidate caches > invalidate and Restart**. Don't bother checking any of the option boxes before clicking on invalidate and Restart.