# Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

I am new in IntelliJ, Maven, and Spring Initializr. I open the unzipped file in IntelliJ. Then, from the right side, I go to the **Project/Lifecycle** and then click the install. After I while, I received an error of *"Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0'"*. From **Sync/pom.xml** I got 2 errors the *"Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0'"* and *"Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2'"*. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/70326701/8203759

Comment: First you should check your build on plain command (not from inside of IDEA)...