# Plugin 'maven-assembly-plugin:' not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Since I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by a `ClassNotFoundException` when running my compiled jar on another machine without maven I figured out the problem is that the jar is not being compiled with the dependencies.

I just started using IntelliJ after a few years of using eclipse, so I get a problem which I can't seem to be able to solve, I get a `Plugin 'maven-assembly-plugin:' not found` error on my pom.xml.

I've tried about every solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij) but it still does not change *anything*.

I'm using IntelliJ build 202.7660.26.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27168770/699665

Comment: Adding the dependency solved the issue and others similar to this.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>