# Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.6.3' not found

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, soap, maven-plugin

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to produce a spring boot soap webservice
in the pom.xml file, I am getting this error

> Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.6.3' not found

```
<properties>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/countries.xsd</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

I have

- java JDK 15
- Apache Maven 3.6.3

both are added to system variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxvzo.png)

Comment: When and where do you get this error? Please post the full output. Does Maven build work from OS terminal?

Comment: Looks like this plugin version does not exist on Maven central repository. The `2.4` version works for me.

Comment: do you suggest to download Apache Maven2 insted of Apache Maven 3

Comment: i got the error righ away when i write this plugin <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version> ,\\ i am not sure about the version i am new to this i tried to find plugin for the version of maven i have put no result i tried several once like this one https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/1.3/ but still did not work

Comment: in the problems tab i got this error :Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.5' not found

Comment: while in the build tab i got this: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:pom:0.14.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: I attached a picture from the repositry in the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij