# Maven java-doc plugin not found in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

In my IntelliJ one of POM is showing error due to plugin not found as per snippet below :

[image]

All my build configuration is correct (as per answer [Maven plugins can not be found in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij))

Below is my IntelliJ settings :
[image]

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Does the build on plain command line work?

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise , mvn clean install is working fine on cmd. Build is successful. But somehow IntelliJ is not reading it correctly even after clicking on Invalidate cache/Restart.

Comment: Which IntelliJ Version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7141.44, built on May 7, 2019

Comment: Please upgrade your IDEA IntelliJ .... it's old... we have 2020.2.3 the next version 2020.3 is already looking around the corner do not try to use old software ... many things have been changed in IDEA for Maven etc.  Apart from that you are using very old versions of plugins ...

Comment: If issue persists with latest version - does it help to declare the plugin's version explicitly there? Also a sample project would be helpful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved only after updating IntelliJ version to 2020.2.3
Issue not resolved in older version but even with this error there is issue no InteLLiJ build and debugger also working without any issue.