# Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Here is the unresolved plugins! [image]

Here is my setting for maven. I'm on mac system.[image]

I tried to reload the project and download resources but doesnt resolve the issues. Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: If marked this as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/.  Please read through all of the answers and see if they resolve your issue.  (If they don't, please update your question with links to each answer that you tried ... and what happened.  So that people don't waste time suggesting the various standard solutions, all over again.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The article did not solve my problem but I figured out how to solve it. I went straight to the directory where those plugins are and deleted them. Then I let inelliJ re-download the dependencies on its own and fixed the problem.

Comment: That is precisely the solution given by https://stackoverflow.com/a/44883900/139985 which is the 3rd answer for the duplink Q&A. Hint: you need to read **ALL** of the answers, not just the one with the most votes.