# Unresolved plugin: 'external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1'

Tags: java, maven

Getting error in my project even comment out Maven plugin, still facing same issue

```
<!--<plugin>
            <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                &lt;!&ndash; required for proper handling of symlinks by jgitflow. Requirements: POSIX and Java7 &ndash;&gt;
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.java7</artifactId>
                    &lt;!&ndash; the same as the one inside jgitflow's dependencies &ndash;&gt;
                    <version>3.7.1.201504261725-r</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>-->
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij

Comment: It's not working for me

Comment: Is it works from command line?