I am encountering an issue within IntelliJ IDEA, specifically as follows:
"unresolved plugin": 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2'
"unresolved plugin": 'org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0'
"unresolved plugin": 'com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.14'
"unresolved plugin": 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0'
"unresolved plugin": 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2'
"unresolved plugin": 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2'
"unresolved plugin": 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2'"And even after applying the steps outlined in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496239/maven-plugins-can-not-be-found-in-intellij/44883900#44883900, the problem remains unsolved, and moreover, several plugins are not found within my local repository."Can anyone help me? Thanks

Maven plugins can not be found in IntelliJ

First build your project on plain command line... furthermore I strongly recommend to upgrade all the plugins you are using? Why do you use wagon-maven-plugin (ancient old!!)...

Does this answer your question? Maven plugins can not be found in IntelliJ

It is a possible duplicate of Maven plugins can not be found in IntelliJ.
Try the following actions starting with the first, and if it doesn't work, move on to the next:

Force the maven re-import



Invalidate your cache (File -> Invalidate caches...)


removing the local cache will not solve the problem.
